# synchronizing node.js calls

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I am writing my first "real" AWS lambda application, and I need to synchronize a couple calls.  There don't appear to be "sync" versions of the methods I am calling.

Specifically, I want to make a call to Dynamo, and then use data parsed from the JSON to make an http request.

After having set it up, here's my working Dynamo call...

```
dynamoDb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        url = parse(data);
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

I then call an http request using that url...

```
http.get(url,function(res){
    res.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });

    res.on('data',function(d){
        console.log("received more chunks");
        chunks += d;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
        console.log("http request complete");
    })
}
```

The problem seems to be that the second call doesn't wait for the first one.  I have looked into using async/await, but I am not sure how I use those with the error handling callbacks.  Examples I have found online are either too general and hard for me to comprehend, or specific without the error handling.

Any idea how I sync these two?

Comment: You've proposed a very reasonable, very common sequence of server-resource interactions here. Modern asynchronous methods in Node.js--including async/await and Promises--were built precisely to deal with cases like this. And I bet this won't be your last AWS lambda call. I hope you learn about these useful techniques in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your `dynamoDb.get` and `http.get` are not synchronised, so the second request (`http.get`) doesn't wait for the first (`dynamoDb.get`) to complete and calls its callback.

To break it down further,

1. `dynamoDb.get` is an asynchronous function that takes a callback. It will call the callback when the request is complete.
2. However, the rest of your code continues to execute immediately after executing `dynamoDb.get(...)` - your code won't wait for the callback to be invoked by `dynamoDb.get`.
3. As such, http.get will run immediately after `dynamoDb.get`, and likely before `dynamoDb.get`'s callback is triggered, resulting in your `url` variable being undefined.

---

In 2023, I wrote [sync-request-curl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request-curl). This library will help with sending synchronous HTTP requests using [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/)'s Easy interface.

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request-curl
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/sync-request-curl

The library contains a subset of the features in the original [sync-request](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request) but leverages [node-libcurl](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl) for better performance and additional libcurl options for NodeJS.

Here is a simple usage with a GET request:

```js
// import request from 'sync-request-curl';
const request = require('sync-request-curl');
const response = request('GET', 'https://ipinfo.io/json');
console.log('Status Code:', response.statusCode);
console.log('body:', response.body.toString());
console.log('json:', JSON.parse(response.body.toString()));
```

Here is an example that more closely resembles your use case:

```js
const request = require('sync-request-curl');

// Assuming your "url" is defined

try {
  const response = request('GET', url);
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.statusCode}`);
  }
  
  // May throw Error if response.body.toString() is not JSON, e.g. HTML
  const jsonBody = JSON.parse(response.body.toString());
  console.log(jsonBody);
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error:", err.message);
}
```

If you can find a way to write `dynamoDb.get` synchronously, you will be able to simply place the code on top of the snippet above.

Otherwise, you can:

1. Use the same structure to make an HTTP request using [sync-request-curl](https://github.com/nktnet1/sync-request-curl) to your dynamoDb API directly
2. Simply place the code snippet above inside the callback function.

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring async/await for the moment, have you tried:

```
dynamoDb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        url = parse(data);
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        http.get(url,function(res) {
            res.on('error', function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });

            res.on('data',function(d){
                console.log("received more chunks");
                chunks += d;
            });

            res.on('end',function(){
                console.log("http request complete");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Syntax error missing closing parenthesis on that http request

Comment: I have tried that, but my example above was only for clarity's sake.  I have a much more complicated program, and would also like to understand why this is not working.